# don't know how to coerce int64 and float64

Tags: python, excel, pandas, statistics

I have a list which is filled form excel file (import to pandas)

```
a=[df.math[0],df.bio[0],df.chemistry[0]]
```

when I pass mean(a) it gives me the following error:

```
don't know how to coerce int64 and float64
```

How to fix it? I tried 
    `a=[float(df.math[0]),float(df.bio[0]),float(df.chemistry[0])]` - but still does not work

What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: Why not use `np.mean(a)` ? There is some reason for it?

Comment: no I forgot about that. But still why it does not work? I am leaning and want to find out.

Comment: Try `df.math.astype(float)[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here the simpliest is use `numpy.mean`:

```
x = np.mean(a)
```

**Sample**:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'math':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'chemistry':[7.3434,8,9,4,2,3],
         'bio':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

x = np.mean(a)
print (x) 
4.114466666666666
```

Pandas solution:

```
x = df.loc[0, ['math','bio','chemistry']].mean()
print (x) 
4.114466666666666
```

Also for me working converting all values to floats:

```
import statistics 

a = [float(df.math[0]),float(df.bio[0]),float(df.chemistry[0])]
x = statistics.mean(a)
print (x) 
4.114466666666667
```

---

```
import statistics 

a = [float(x) for x in a]
x = statistics.mean(a)
print (x) 
4.114466666666667
```